# how to test a angular2 web application which is in localhost on android phone?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, networking

i developed a web application in angular2 which runs on node server, how can i test this on mobile.

i tried by taking ip address from ifconfig(i use linux) for eg :192.168.43.218 and then adding port number to it like 4201

in phone entered below url

url: http://192.168.43.218:4201

this doesn't work, says 'this site can't be reached'. Any idea on this?